# Bootstrap popover destroys content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a Rails app with the following HTML and coffeescript:

```
<span id="CEO_portrait"><%= image_tag "CEO_portrait.png", class: "portrait" %></span>
<div id="tooltip_container">
  <div id="CEO_biography">
    "The CEO founded the company in 1969."
  </div>
</div>

$ ->
  $('#CEO_portrait').popover
    title: "James E. Lee"
    placement: "top"
    trigger: "hover"
    html: true
    container: "#tooltip_container"
    content: ->
      $('#CEO_biography')
```

The popover appears with the appropriate content the first time my mouse hovers over the '#CEO_portrait" span. However, when my mouse leaves the span, the div with id "CEO_biography" is removed. As a result, when I hover my mouse over '#CEO_portrait' again, the title shows up but not the content. I can't figure out why this is happening. How do I get the content to persist?

Answer (score 0):

http://bootply.com/88701

```
<span id="CEO_portrait">test</span>
  <div id="tooltip_container">
  <div id="CEO_biography">
     "The CEO founded the company in 1969."
  </div>
 </div>
```

It works for me here in bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 2.3.2

Yes the content goes away but the next time I hover the content is still on the popover.  Take a look at the example..

Make sure you have all of your bootstrap scripts/css loaded etc..

Comment: @user1380016 please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Save the content outside of the event:

```
$ ->
 myContent = $('#CEO_biography') // save the content for future use

 $('#CEO_portrait').popover
 title: "James E. Lee"
 placement: "top"
 trigger: "hover"
 html: true
 // container: "#tooltip_container" // I don't know why you use this
 content: ->
   myContent
```

Here is my working solution that uses data attributes:

```
$("[data-toggle='popover-div']").each ->
 that = $(this)
 content = $(that.data("content-div")) // Save content of the id given in "data-content-div"

 that.popover
   html: true
   content: ->
     content
```

Jade

```
a.btn.btn-share(data-toggle="popover-div", data-content-div="#share-popover",
data-trigger="click", data-placement="top")
  | Share <i class="fa fa-share"></i>

.share-popover-wrapper // Display: none
  #share-popover
   // [... Content goes here ...]
```